# Is there a way to procedurally generate screenshots of a set of elements within an HTML document?

Tags: automation, html, screenshot

I've got a webpage with a table that has a large number of rows, and I'd really like to be able to generate a screenshot of each of the `<tr>` elements within it without having to do it manually. Is there a method which can iterate over HTML elements (like table rows) and generate a screenshot for each of them?

Unfortunately, all of the results I've been able to find for web screenshot automation are intended for full-page screenshots created on a timed interval, and not for 'slicing' a webpage into many screenshots once.

Comment: Asking for tools is off topic here.

Comment: You're not likely to find a "ready-made" tool for snapshotting rows of a table from a html document. This is much too specialized a task for a generic tool in my opinion. Look into Selenium and/or Puppeteer if you wish to pursue this path. Also, edit your question to conform to the guidelines, or it will be closed.

Comment: I've removed the reference to "tools" from the question! Also, while my specific need in this instance is for table rows, having a method through which I could snapshot any arbitrary element(s) programmatically is what I'm looking for - not just table rows.

Comment: Also, I've gone and looked at the "[few suggestions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software)" about how to ask this question given in the 'closed' message, and I feel like I literally did what they suggested, word for word, in my initial asking of the question. I don't understand why simply including the possibility that the solution _might_ be a tool warrants this closure.

Comment: `$ lynx --dump www.google.com`  - try it on "your" webpage